# apereo CAS to Angular/Spring boot application

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cas

I am developing an application using Angular6 for frontend and spring boot for backend.

Currently what I have is a frontend application that calls my spring boot APIs. At the moment all APIs are available to everyone for example localhost:8080/api/get_data

Now I have to implement authentication using APEREO CAS protocol https://www.apereo.org/projects/cas If I am understanding correctly I'd have to check every API request if it contains some session cookie where authentitacion is stored... I'm a bit lost so any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:
1) Enable spring security in your spring-boot application.
2) Convert your spring-boot application to spring-boot cas client. Read the below article
[spring-security-cas-sso](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-cas-sso)

Baam your application is secured and will only be accessible once cas has authenticated.

Hope this helps.